# Webstorm 2016.1 can't open js files

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I updated my Webstorm to 2016.1.1, all fine so far. I can open all sorts of files (in editor), but I can't open any of my *.js files. I also tried to restart Webstorm/Computer several times and closed/reopened my project.

Someone stumbled across that same issue?

Comment: I'll try updating WS now and take a look. In the meantime, do you think you could be a little more specific about how it's not working? For example, does the IDE give you an error when you try to open a JS file, or perhaps when you double click on the file it opens with a different program?

Comment: It just did nothing. Really nothing. But I solved the problem by reinstalling it. Two reasons are possible: 1.) First installiation, I took the settings from my previous webstorm, maybe he has some errors there 2.) First installation, I installed the new version over the other version, could have been also the problem. Just reinstall and it works ;)

Comment: Sweet, well done! You should add an answer so that people who search the same issue can find the resolution easily

Comment: I am hesitant, is this off-topic?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by reinstalling it.

Two reasons are possible:

1.) First installiation, I took the settings from my previous webstorm, maybe he has some errors there

2.) First installation, I installed the new version over the other version, could have been also the problem.

Just reinstall and it works ;)